# pytesseract not recognizing negative number image properly

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have the following picture with the number -1.49. The problem is that this is already a very small number on the screen, so it is pixelated.

Any pointers on how I can improve this? It is very important that I read this number correctly
[the image I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRebB.png)

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
 # Open an image file
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    image_path = 'large_scale_numbers.png'
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    # Use Tesseract OCR to extract text
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 8 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.,-'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,  lang='eng', config=custom_config)

    # Print the extracted text
    print("Extracted Text:", text)
```

returns
Extracted Text: 41.49

Comment: `pytesseract` may have problem when text is too small. And it prefers black text on white background. You can read more in `Tesseract` doc: [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). But you use `PIL.Image` so you can easily `resize()` image and `invert()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives me empty string for your image

But when I resize it `x2` then I get correct result - but for different `psm`

```
img = Image.open(image_path)

w, h = img.size

img = img.resize((w*2, h*2), Image.Resampling.NEAREST)
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

```
from PIL import Image  #, ImageOps
import pytesseract
 # Open an image file
#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
image_path = 'image.png'

img = Image.open(image_path)
w, h = img.size
print('old size:', w, h)
new_w = w * 2
new_h = h * 2
print('new size:', new_w, new_h)
img = img.resize((new_w, new_h), Image.Resampling.NEAREST)

#img = inverted_image = ImageOps.invert(img)  # invert colors

#img.save('new_image.png')

# Use Tesseract OCR to extract text
for psm in range(0, 14):
    try:
        custom_config = fr'--oem 3 --psm {psm} -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.,-'
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,  lang='eng', config=custom_config)
        text = text.strip()  # remove `new line` at the end of text
        # Print the extracted text
        print(f"{psm:3} | Extracted Text:", text)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"{psm:3} | Exception:", ex)
```

Result:

```
old size: 41 24
new size: 82 48
  0 | Exception: (1, 'Warning, detects only orientation with -l eng Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Estimating resolution as 234 Too few characters. Skipping this page Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')
  1 | Extracted Text: -1.49
  2 | Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_wp42qbtd.txt'
  3 | Extracted Text: -1.49
  4 | Extracted Text: -1.49
  5 | Extracted Text: 8
7
  6 | Extracted Text: -1.49
  7 | Extracted Text: -1.49
  8 | Extracted Text: 
  9 | Extracted Text: 
 10 | Extracted Text: -1.49
 11 | Extracted Text: -1.49
 12 | Extracted Text: -1.49
 13 | Extracted Text:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a solution with `cv2` as addition to the above solution.
[Page Segmentation Mode](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) (psm): 7 Treat the image as a single text line. The oem values are described [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc). Important is a black & white image in the right size.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Open an image file
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
image_file = "149.png"

image = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print('Original Dimensions : ',image.shape)

# resize image
scale_percent = 200 # play with the size - percent of original size
width = int(rgb.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(rgb.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(rgb, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)

# Use Tesseract OCR to extract text
custom_config = r'--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=_-01234567890.'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized,  lang='eng', config=custom_config)

# Print the extracted text
print("Extracted Text:", text)

cv2.imshow('Resized', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output;
[image]